# Adding long press to dynamically generated menu items

Tags: android

Okay, so I have a dynamic menu (In my navigation drawer), generated like so:

In my Main.java `onCreate()`:

```
DatabaseManager databaseAccess = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
databaseAccess.open();
List<String> folders = databaseAccess.getFolders();
databaseAccess.close();

// Set up the menu items
setupMenu(folders);
```

This gets the headings into an array called 'folders', then runs the `setupMenu` function:

```
private void setupMenu(List<String> folders) {
    // Sets up the menu
    Log.i("Folder Size",String.valueOf(folders.size()));
    NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    int x = 0;
    while(x < folders.size()) {
        menu.add(R.id.myfolders,Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,folders.get(x++));
    }
    navView.invalidate();
}
```

Which adds it to the `id:myfolders` in `activity_main_drawer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item android:title="My Folders"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/myfolders">
        <menu></menu>
    </item>

    <item android:checkableBehavior="single" android:orderInCategory="2">
        <menu android:id="@+id/about_menu">
            <item  android:id="@+id/system_about"
                    android:title="About"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info" />
            </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

This all works perfectly, however I want to add longpress functionality to my menu items.  I have no idea how to go about doing this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `MenuItem` from `menu.add()` then you can call:

```
menuItem.getActionView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return false; // true
    }
});
```

But not before you set action view: `menuItem.setActionView(new ImageButton(this))`.

Comment: Thank you - I got it working - From the `View v` object though how will i tell which menu item I am clicking?

Comment: try this v.getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());

Comment: Hello, I am having a problem with this code, can you please see my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741645/navmenu-onlongclick-functioning-weirdly

Comment: for what ever it worth, try replacing new View with new ImageButton

Comment: Thanks.  It makes it a bit easier, although its not ideal :(